# Subtract days, months, years from a date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Does anybody know of a simple way of taking a date (e.g. Today) and going back X days, X months and X years?

I have tried that:

```
var date = new Date();
$("#searchDateFrom").val((date.getMonth() -1 ) + '/' + (date.getDate() - 6) + '/' + (date.getFullYear() - 1));
```

But I got a negative date, for example today the output was:

> 3/-3/2015

Any advise?

Thanks.

Comment: `date.get....` will return a `Number` and if you are subtracting number from another `number`, value can be negative(If left value is smaller).. I would suggest you to use `DateObj.set...` methods and then retrieve the respective values...

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You are simply reducing the values from a number. So substracting 6 from 3 (date) will return -3 only.

You need to individually add/remove unit of time in date object

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate( date.getDate() - 6 );
date.setFullYear( date.getFullYear() - 1 );
$("#searchDateFrom").val((date.getMonth() ) + '/' + (date.getDate()) + '/' + (date.getFullYear()));
```

Comment: getMonth() is zero based. Meaning it will show the wrong month. Example: 10 is november.

Comment: let's just say: getMonth() is index based.

Comment: But `getMinutes()` for example isn't index-based. So it's fair to say the inconsistency is wrong as @Tony puts it.

Answer (score 33):

As others have said you're subtracting from the numeric values returned from methods like `date.getDate()`, you need to reset those values on your date variable. I've created a method below that will do this for you. It creates a date using `new Date()` which will initialize with the current date, then sets the date, month, and year according to the values passed in. For example, if you want to go back 6 days then pass in -6 like so `var newdate = createDate(-6,0,0)`. If you don't want to set a value pass in a zero (or you could set default values). The method will return the new date for you (tested in Chrome and Firefox).

```
function createDate(days, months, years) {
        var date = new Date(); 
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
        date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + years);
        return date;    
    }
```

Answer (score 23):

**2021 Update:**

MomentJS has been replaced/improved with LuxonJS, a much more up-to-date and newer version. You can find it here: https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/

I'll leave the old post for now, since it could sitll help others.

**Old post:**

I'd recommend using the MomentJS libraries. They make all interactions with Dates a lot simpler.

If you use Moment, your code would be as simple as this:

```
var today = moment();
var nextMonth = today.add('month', 1);
// note that both variables `today` and `nextMonth` refer to 
// the next month at this point, because `add` mutates in-place
```

You can find MomentJS here: http://momentjs.com/

**UPDATE:**

In JavaScript, the Date.getDate() function returns the current day of the month from 1-31. You are subtracting 6 from this number, and it is currently the 3rd of the month. This brings the value to -3.

Comment: @Fvb Thank you, I read the guide and it's an excellent library, thank you for the idea to use it.

Comment: Keep in mind that moment.js adds about 16k to your app. Not a big deal usually. But if performance is critical, sticking to plain old js is cheaper for such a small computation.

Comment: current version of moment (2.18.2 as of this writing) gives a warning on this function. add/subtract('period', number) is deprecated, and suggests you use add/subtract(number, 'period') instead.

Comment: For anyone looking here in 2021, moment.js isn't the best library to use anymore. luxon.js is its successor, and there are many other modern alternatives.

Answer (score 16):

This is a pure-function which takes a passed-in starting date, building on Phil's answer:

```
function deltaDate(input, days, months, years) {
    return new Date(
      input.getFullYear() + years, 
      input.getMonth() + months, 
      Math.min(
        input.getDate() + days,
        new Date(input.getFullYear() + years, input.getMonth() + months + 1, 0).getDate()
      )
    );
}
```

e.g. writes the date one month ago to the console log:

```
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(), 0, -1, 0));
```

e.g. subtracts a month from March 30, 2020:

```
console.log(deltaDate(new Date(2020, 2, 30), 0, -1, 0)); // Feb 29, 2020
```

Note that this works even if you go past the end of the month or year.

**Update:** As the example above shows, this has been updated to handle variances in the number of days in a month.

Comment: But it will have weird behaviour at the end of months. March 29 - 1 month = February 29, which will result in March 1. March 31 + 1 month = April 31, which will result in May 1. Depending on your use case, that might not be what you expected.

Comment: Thank you @Johanneke, I have updated the code to address this.

Comment: The day correction makes this answer very useful, thanks!

Comment: This function fails when adding positive days: Today, `deltaDate(new Date(), +4000, 0, 0)` returns Aug 31 2023 which is off by some ten years.

Answer (score 12):

I implemented a function similar to the **momentjs** method **subtract**.

### - If you use Javascript

```js
function addDate(dt, amount, dateType) {
  switch (dateType) {
    case 'days':
      return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + amount) && dt;
    case 'weeks':
      return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + (7 * amount)) && dt;
    case 'months':
      return dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + amount) && dt;
    case 'years':
      return dt.setFullYear( dt.getFullYear() + amount) && dt;
  }
}
```

**example:**

```js
let dt = new Date();
dt = addDate(dt, -1, 'months');// use -1 to subtract
```

## - If you use Typescript:

```js
export enum dateAmountType {
  DAYS,
  WEEKS,
  MONTHS,
  YEARS,
}

export function addDate(dt: Date, amount: number, dateType: dateAmountType): Date {
  switch (dateType) {
    case dateAmountType.DAYS:
      return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + amount) && dt;
    case dateAmountType.WEEKS:
      return dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + (7 * amount)) && dt;
    case dateAmountType.MONTHS:
      return dt.setMonth(dt.getMonth() + amount) && dt;
    case dateAmountType.YEARS:
      return dt.setFullYear( dt.getFullYear() + amount) && dt;
  }
}
```

**example:**

```js
let dt = new Date();
dt = addDate(dt, -1, 'months'); // use -1 to subtract
```

## Optional (unit-tests)

I also made some unit-tests for this function using **Jasmine**:

```js
  it('addDate() should works properly', () => {
    for (const test of [
      { amount: 1,  dateType: dateAmountType.DAYS,   expect: '2020-04-13'},
      { amount: -1, dateType: dateAmountType.DAYS,   expect: '2020-04-11'},
      { amount: 1,  dateType: dateAmountType.WEEKS,  expect: '2020-04-19'},
      { amount: -1, dateType: dateAmountType.WEEKS,  expect: '2020-04-05'},
      { amount: 1,  dateType: dateAmountType.MONTHS, expect: '2020-05-12'},
      { amount: -1, dateType: dateAmountType.MONTHS, expect: '2020-03-12'},
      { amount: 1,  dateType: dateAmountType.YEARS,  expect: '2021-04-12'},
      { amount: -1, dateType: dateAmountType.YEARS,  expect: '2019-04-12'},
    ]) {
      expect(formatDate(addDate(new Date('2020-04-12'), test.amount, test.dateType))).toBe(test.expect);
    }

  });
```

To use this test you need this function:

```js
// get format date as 'YYYY-MM-DD'
export function formatDate(date: Date): string {
  const d     = new Date(date);
  let month   = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  let day     = '' + d.getDate();
  const year  = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2)  {
    month = '0' + month;
  }
  if (day.length < 2) {
    day = '0' + day;
  }

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

Comment: shorter formatDate "hack":

function formatDate(date = new Date()) {
    return date.toLocaleString('sv').substring(0,10);
}

Comment: For formatDate you don't have to get weird with `toLocaleString`. Use `toISOString.substring(0,10)`.

Comment: More important note: `addDate(new Date('2021-07-31'), -3, 'months')` gives 2021-05-01 when it should be 2021-04-30.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [moment.js](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for time and date management.

```
import moment = require('moment');

const now = moment();

now.subtract(7, 'seconds'); // 7 seconds ago
now.subtract(7, 'days');    // 7 days and 7 seconds ago
now.subtract(7, 'months');  // 7 months, 7 days and 7 seconds ago
now.subtract(7, 'years');   // 7 years, 7 months, 7 days and 7 seconds ago
// because `now` has been mutated, it no longer represents the current time
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. To be more precise: "Before version 2.8.0, the `subtract(String, Number)` syntax was also supported. It has been deprecated in favor of `subtract(Number, String)`".

Comment: For anyone looking here in 2021, moment.js isn't the best library to use anymore. luxon.js is its successor, and there are many other modern alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

The oneliner to get for instance the date of yesterday would be:

```
const yesterday = ((date) => date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1) && date)(new Date());
```

It will define an arrow function which receives the `new Date()` as a parameter (date). The reason to make an arrow function is that the new Date object will be used multiple times. First to retrieve the current days (getDate), then to set the days (setDate) and also to return it as a result. So it will return the mutated date, not the original date.

Now this arrow function is defined and will be called immediately with the `new Date()` in order to return the date of yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

I have a simpler answer, which works perfectly for days; for months, it's +-2 days:

```
let today=new Date();
const days_to_subtract=30;
let new_date= new Date(today.valueOf()-(days_to_subtract*24*60*60*1000));
```

You get the idea - for months, multiply by 30; but that will be +-2 days.

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla JS `Date` saves the time as milliseconds from [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) (1970), so all we need to do is subtract in milliseconds.
if we want to subtract 10 days we would subtract 1000(ms) * 60(s) * 60(m) * 24(h) * 10(d)

A simple Vanilla function to subtract from a date (notice the `years` exception):

```js
subtractFromDate(new Date(), { hours: 15 }) // now - 15 hours
```

```js
subtractFromDate(new Date(), { days: 15 }) // now - 15 days
```

```js
subtractFromDate(new Date(), { years: 15 }) // now - 15 years
```

```js
const subtractFromDate = (
    date,
    { years, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds } = {}
) => {
    const millisecondsOffset = milliseconds ?? 0
    const secondsOffset = seconds ? 1000 * seconds : 0
    const minutesOffset = minutes ? 1000 * 60 * minutes : 0
    const hoursOffset = hours ? 1000 * 60 * 60 * hours : 0
    const daysOffset = days ? 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days : 0
    const dateOffset =
        millisecondsOffset +
        secondsOffset +
        minutesOffset +
        hoursOffset +
        daysOffset

    let newDate = date
    if (years) newDate = date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - years)
    newDate = new Date(newDate - dateOffset)

    return newDate
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer the question fully, but for anyone who is able to calculate the number of days by which they would like to offset an initial date then the following method will work:

```
myDate.setUTCDate(myDate.getUTCDate() + offsetDays);
```

offsetDays can be positive or negative and the result will be correct for any given initial date with any given offset.