# How to get the last six months from todays date within array and return that array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime

I have one date array as per the following

```
let dateArray= [
      {
        _id: "1234567",
         reqDt: "2019-03-10T13:24:09.000Z"
      },
      {
        _id: "1234567",
          reqDt: "2019-02-10T13:24:09.000Z"
       },
      {
        _id: "1234567",
        reqDt: "2019-07-10T13:24:09.000Z"

      },
      {
        _id: "1234567",
          reqDt: "2019-01-10T13:24:09.000Z"

      },
      {
        _id: "1234567",
        reqDt: "2019-03-10T13:24:09.000Z"
      }
    ];
```

In this date array I want the compare the dates from the array and I want the date between last six month from todays date and return that array which contain the last 6 months array from todays date.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract days, months, years from a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002681/subtract-days-months-years-from-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Any attempt to do it by yourself ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `Array.filter` and a date comparison:

```js
let dateArray= [
  {
    _id: "1234567",
     reqDt: "2019-03-10T13:24:09.000Z"
  },
  {
    _id: "1234567",
      reqDt: "2019-02-10T13:24:09.000Z"
   },
  {
    _id: "1234567",
    reqDt: "2019-07-10T13:24:09.000Z"

  },
  {
    _id: "1234567",
      reqDt: "2019-01-10T13:24:09.000Z"

  },
  {
    _id: "1234567",
    reqDt: "2019-03-10T13:24:09.000Z"
  }
];

const sixMonthsAgo = new Date();
sixMonthsAgo.setMonth(sixMonthsAgo.getMonth() - 6);

console.log(dateArray.filter(({reqDt}) => (new Date(reqDt)) > sixMonthsAgo));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use moment (or dayjs - shares the same API) for that.